# Upgrade maven.2.0.8 to maven.2.0.9 on Ubuntu Hardy Heron (8.04)

Tags: maven-2, ubuntu-8.04

Ubuntu packages for 8.04 only goes upto version 2.0.8 of Maven.  How do I install maven 2.0.9 package using apt-get or other Ubuntu package installer ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to download and install a `.deb` from the ["maven2" package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/maven2). Not sure this will work though.

But actually, my advice would be to install Maven manually ([download the distribution](http://maven.apache.org/download.html), extract it, add `$M2_HOME/bin` to the `$PATH` and there you go).